# GMap.Net for WPF Map Position is not updating when Zooming

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, gmap.net

My **WPF** application UserControl contains a **GMap** control.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Test.test.Map"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:gmmapeprovider="clr-namespace:GMap.NET.MapProviders;assembly=GMap.NET.Core"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/" 
             xmlns:windowspresentation="clr-namespace:GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation;assembly=GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation" prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
                <Grid >
                    <windowspresentation:GMapControl 
                    x:Name="mapView" MinZoom="1" 
                    Position="{Binding MapPosition}" 
                    MaxZoom="17" 
                    Zoom="{Binding MapZoom}" 
                    MouseWheelZoomEnabled="True"
                    MouseWheelZoomType ="MousePositionWithoutCenter" 
                    MapProvider="{x:Static gmmapeprovider:GoogleMapProvider.Instance}" 
                    CacheLoc="{Binding XmlFilePath}"
                    IgnoreMarkerOnMouseWheel="True"/>
                </Grid>
      </UserControl>
```

[image]

The Map **Position** is bound to **MapPosition** Property in the UserControl's ViewModel. Each time I Pan the Map using the right mouse button, click and drag function, the value of the **MapPosition** is updated.

**Here's my concern:**
My expectation is the value of the Position should also be updated if the map is zoomed, while the mouse pointer is not on the center of the control. Apparently, this is not the case, the Position remains unchanged, unless if the map is panned once more.

Am I missing some settings here, or are there any possible workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the [source code](https://github.com/marlond18/GMap.NET/blob/master/GMap.NET/GMap.NET.WindowsPresentation/GMapControl.cs), starting from line [1740 until 1748](https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET/pull/116/commits/9e94568194692a450d635131345ab425a1f24a93#), it turns out that the very `_core._position` is the one being updated instead of the `GMapControl.Position` during MouseWheel Zooming. which means that the UI control itself does not know that the position was been changed apparently.

here's the [pull request](https://github.com/judero01col/GMap.NET/pull/116) I have made, hopefully, it gets by the owner.
I have just replaced the `_core._position` to `Position`.